# Yii2 Tabs widget not changing state after setting to active

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, yii2

I have made two buttons for switching views on 2 tabs. Every button corresponds to different tab and contents under the `Tabs::widget` is properly updated but the highlighted tab is not changing unlike when the tab is pressed. What else am I missing?

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\Tabs;
?>

<?=
    Html::button("1", [ 
        'class' => 'btn btn-info', 
        'id' => 'criticalTab', 
        'style' => 'position:relative; left:20px; background-color:red;',
        ] )
?>

<?=
    Html::button("2", [ 
        'class' => 'btn btn-info', 
        'id' => 'warningTab', 
        'style' => 'position:relative; left:30px; background-color:orange;',
        ] )
?>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $("#criticalTab").click(function(){
            $("#tab1").addClass('active');
            $("#tab2").removeClass('active');
        });
        $("#warningTab").click(function(){
            $("#tab1").removeClass('active');
            $("#tab2").addClass('active');
        });
    });
</script>

<div style="position:relative; left:0px; top:30px"> 
        <?= 
            Tabs::widget([
                'items' => [
                    [
                        'label' => 'Critical',
                        'options' => ['id' => 'tab1'],
                        'content' => 'hello'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => 'Warning',
                        'options' => ['id' => 'tab2'],
                        'content' => 'hi'
                    ],
                ],
            ]);
        ?>
</div>
```

Comment: it's working for me, no errors. Class successfully changing for both tabs.

Comment: yeah it's working but the tabs highlighted are not changing. Am I wrong?

Comment: tabs are also highlighted when changed.

Comment: Its working properly for me too no error. Tabs are also highlighted.Check your console if there are some java script errors

Comment: Hi! I just updated my code and there are no errors on console. pressing button 1 and button 2 affects the content of the tab widget and yes they display the desired content but the tab (highlighted) is not changing. The highlighted tab always is just `Critical`. What do you think is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on 1 or 2 button , they don't fire the click event of tabs. Change your script code to below one.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $("#criticalTab").click(function(){

       $('.nav-tabs').find('a[href="#tab1"]').trigger('click');

    });
    $("#warningTab").click(function(){
      $('.nav-tabs').find('a[href="#tab2"]').trigger('click');

    });

});
</script>
```

You have to bind the click event of tabs with required buttons.

Comment: If this solves your problem then mark them as a true.

Comment: can you explain the `.nav-tabs` part please? Thanks

Comment: You are using bootstrap tab widget, that generates the tab in ul li format. If you will see generated html of tabs then you can see there is a class .nav-tabs. and we are binding the click event to that li.

Comment: what will happen if i ommit the class and just use `$('a[href="#tab1"]').trigger('click');`?

Comment: when you will ommit the class then it will search the a[href="#tab1"] in the whole document. and if we want to find the element in the specified area then we can use .nav-tabs class or any parent element. This is up to our requirement.